# Create tags without questions in teams?

Tags: support, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

Is it possible (as an admin) to create tags without creating questions on Stack Overflow for teams?

For example, we just set up a new team and we want to make it easy for our engineers to create questions using some of our pre-made tags. These pre-made tags would represent internal tools for example.

Or is it better to just wait and see if people tag items themselves?

This is easily handled in normal Stack Overflow because there are thousands of tags already and users need rep to create new ones. However in teams, users don't need a lot of rep (I believe it is 1) and you don't start with any of the pre-existing non-teams tags.

Comment: When you go to the tags view you cannot manually add tags, maybe there's another view?

Comment: Edit an existing question to create new tags. Then revert edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our Free and Basic plans of Stack Overflow for Teams don't have the capability to upload tags proactively. However, our Business plan does allow for a csv upload of tags as an option under Admin Settings.

As someone else mentioned in the comments, there are ways around this if you want to add tags proactively.